# Babbage's number with C++ not showing proper results

Tags: c++

I was given a question to find babbage's number (A number whose square ends with 269696, for example 99736 squared is 9947269696, thus being a Babbage Number). My implementation in C++ is provided below. It is not providing the desired results. The first result is correct, but the subsequent ones are not. I probably think that it has to do with casting, or the variables getting out of range. But upon checking with the range of `unsigned long long int` , I can't understand what is wrong with my code.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    unsigned long long square = 0;

    for(int i = 519; i < 100000; i++){

        square = i*i;    

        if(square % 1000000 == 269696)
            cout<<"Number: "<<i<<", Square: "<<square<<endl;

    }

}
```

This is the output I'm getting :

```
Number: 25264, Square: 638269696
Number: 119328, Square: 1354269696
Number: 158816, Square: 18446744073162269696
Number: 186992, Square: 606269696
Number: 188008, Square: 987269696
Number: 331424, Square: 18446744071882269696
Number: 439080, Square: 18446744073227269696
```

I do see that the squares are also inaccurate, but I don't understand why.

Here's the list of Babbage's number

25264
99736
150264
224736
275264
349736
400264
474736
525264
599736
650264
724736
775264
849736
900264
974736

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is a `signed int`. Since e.g. `99736 * 99736` is much larger than even an `unsigned int` can handle on all common platforms you will have arithmetic overflow by the multiplication, and for signed integer types that leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to make `i` an `unsigned long long` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the data type of variable `i` from `signed integer` to `unsigned integer`. You are getting the wrong square of the number because of [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

```
size_t square = 0;

for(size_t i = 519; i < 100000; i++){
    square = i*i;    
    if(square % 1000000 == 269696)
        cout<<"Number: "<<i<<", Square: "<< square <<"\n";
}
```

As pointed by [Some Programmer Dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) in the comment, if you are working on 32-bit machine then you need to use `unsigned long long` otherwise `size_t` will perfectly on 64-bit machine.

Comment: Considering that `unsigned int` on all common platforms is 32 bits, and the second Babbage number is well above nine billions, that won't be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Make Changes into the type of `int i` variable `unsigned long long i`.

As when you are calculating multiplication of `int * int` for some ranges it's exceed the range of int may results into the undefined behaviour.

```html
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    unsigned long long square = 0;

    for(unsigned long long i = 519; i < 100000; i++){

        square = i*i;    

        if(square % 1000000 == 269696)
            cout<<"Number: "<<i<<", Square: "<<square<<endl;

    }

}
```